# Can't Configure ESF or linecode on C2921/k9

Tags: cisco, router

I have 4 VWIC2-2MFT-T1/E1 installed on a C2921 router running Version 15.3(3)M2, everytime I enter the framing esf and linecode b8zs, the router accepts the commands but the controller remains with the following configs:

```
controller T1 0/0/0
 cablelength long 0db
 channel-group 1 timeslots 1-24
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

That is because those are the default values. You will find that when doing `show run` on Cisco devices, the default values will not show up.

Another example of this is to set the time zone to UTC 0. That is the default time zone, and it will not show in the  `show run` configuration. If you set the time zone to anything else it will be in the configuration that you see.

Comment: In 12.1, the config will show up on the controller which led to the confusion.